# Bootstrap datetimepicker moment format issue

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, momentjs

Alright I am having an issue with getting dates to display as intended when using the bootstrap datetimepicker.  I know it runs off moment.js for the formatting but it doesn't seem to be following the normal set of rules for moment (I am using the newest versions of both).

For example if I were to take a date and create a regular moment() object out of it and then format it with MMMM that would give me the full month name (February)

moment('02/24/2015')->format('MMMM'); // gives February

But if I am working with a datetimepicker object and set the format on it, it will end up outputting (FebruraryFebruary) and if I just want the full month name I need to go with MM.

$(input).datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM'
}) // gives February

Can anyone explain why it does not follow the correct moment formatting rules?  I find it odd (and difficult to get the result I want because I cannot find the rules I need to set to get what I am looking for) that I cannot just take my standard moment formatting rules and apply it to the datetimepicker and get the intended result.

halp!

Comment: Upgrade to latest version 'MMMM' on bootstrap datetimepicker and momentjs both give February

Comment: epic fail on my part. I had copied the new datetimepicker code into the file but it didn't upload.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Moment format and BootStrap DatetimePicker format works differently.
Never set Momment format into Datetimepicker format.

Consider this:
datetimeformat `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP` for Bootstrap DatetimePicker AM format
and the equivalent in momment format is given below:

```
MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A
```

Check Momment.JS site for more information